# How to delete selected text in a console application

Tags: c#, .net

How can I select what was printed on the screen and delete with backspace?

like selecting with ctrl + shift + left arrow and backspace

[image]

This is the code I am using for deleting and it is working great so far:

```
Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.CursorLeft - 1, Console.CursorTop);
Console.Write(" "); 
Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.CursorLeft - 1, Console.CursorTop);
```

Comment: Are you asking how to this in code, or actually in the command window?

Comment: Please be more specific. What is it that you can't get to work? You say you already can clear text from the screen and "it is working great". Do you know how to get input from the user, i.e. detect the backspace key? Do you know how to get the coordinates of the current selection? Do you know how to retrieve the text in the current selection? Are you trying to set the selection yourself, or just find out what it is? There are a lot of unknowns in your question, making it far too broad at best, and fundamentally unclear.